# Is there way to redirect strapi error messages which I see in UI to the stdout?

Tags: strapi

I am using the **Strapi v3.0.0-beta.18.7** UI and the error in the UI are shown partly so it is impossible to read the full text of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use a custom middleware to manage your needs.

Here is the documentation to create a middleware - https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/middlewares.html

**Step 1: Create the middleware**

**Path** — `middlewares/log/index.js`

```js
module.exports = strapi => {
  return {
    initialize() {
      strapi.app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
        await next();

        const status = ctx.status;

        if (status < 200 || status >= 300) {
          console.log(ctx.body);
        }
      });
    },
  };
};
```

**Step 2: Enable the middleware**

**Path** — `config/environments/development/middleware.json`

```
{
  "log": {
    "enabled": true
  }
}
```

**Step 3: Set the middleware in the right order**

**Path** — `config/middleware.json`

```
{
  "timeout": 100,
  "load": {
    "before": [
      "log",
      "responseTime",
      "logger",
      "cors",
      "responses",
      "gzip"
    ],
    "order": [
      "Define the middlewares' load order by putting their name in this array is the right order"
    ],
    "after": [
      "parser",
      "router"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Great, let me know if you have other questions.